# How to resolve this Future when passing it down to my view page

Tags: scala, playframework

I am having an issue in my Play action where my view page requires a ApiResponse object but I am a Future[ApiResponse] and can't seem to "unwrap" the future.

```
  def confirm(token: String) = Action async { request =>
    // loadTokenInfo returns Future[Option[SP]]
    loadTokenInfo(token).map  { maybeSP =>
      maybeSP match {
        case Some(sp) =>
          val someConfig = SomeConfiguration(..)
          // confirmSubscription returns Future[ApiResponse]
          for {
            apiResp <- apiService.confirmSubscription(sp.account, sp.website, sp.list, sp.listMember)
          } yield Ok(views.html.subscription.confirm(ConfirmPageViewModel(someConfig, sp, apiResp)))

        case _ =>
          Ok(views.html.errorpage.empty(PageNotFound("asdf")))
      }
    }
  }
```

I am getting the error:

> [error]  found   : scala.concurrent.Future[play.api.mvc.Result]
>   [error]  required: play.api.mvc.Result

I tried to map over the apiResp also but that didn't work:

```
apiResp.map { r =>
  Ok(views.html.subscription.confirm(ConfirmPageViewModel(pageConfig, sp, r)))
}
```

Do I have to call Await.result here?  I don't want to block obviously but not sure what to do at this point.

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing since you have't specified where the error happens and what `confirmSubscription` returns--presumably a `Future` of something.

But I can say that at least you need to return this in your default case:

```
Future.successful(Ok(views.html.errorpage.empty(PageNotFound("asdf"))))
```

And for the love of all that is right with the world, don't use `Await.result`.

Some random, unrelated notes:

- Using `map` and `getOrElse` is more idiomatic than a pattern match on `Option`.
- It would be nice if `confirmSubscription` just took an `sp` instance and let the `apiService` decide how it needs to use it.
- I prefer mapping over `Future`s rather than using `for` comprehensions--as you did already--when there is only one.

Comment: And you should use `flatMap` after `loadTokenInfo`

Comment: Not so sure about that since I think that returns an `Option` of something rather than a `Future`, but since no information is given about the types of these functions, it's hard to say.

Comment: confirmSubscription returns a Future[ApiResponse]

Comment: Now that I see your other edit, if you're dealing a lot with `Future[Option[T]]`, you should look at monad transformers like `OptionT` in scalaz. Makes life so much easier. But anyway, looks like @vdebergue is right then.